# How to create column in select statement where row is sorted numerically in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sorting

I want to create a column in my SELECT statement where it would have numbers in order, similar to this:

```
Column A| Primary_Key| Column C
       1|          1 | AValue
       2|          3 | BAValue
       3|          2 | CValue
```

I need to create this column because My sorting order would depend on other parameters, however, I am using column A for another type of sorting in my code.

My current SQL is similar to this:

```
SELECT * from table1 order by // whatever column I need to order it by.
```

How do I create the column to just make the count from 1 - whatever the last value is without affecting my query?

Comment: really dont understand the question, can you provide sample data and expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are wanting to have a column to count the rows ordered by `[Column C]`. If so, you could use:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Column C]) [Column A],
   Primary_key,
   [Column C]
from Table1
```

This new column `Column A` can be ordered by any column you want (you just need to change the code `ORDER BY [Column C]`).

Not thinking about your case, it is possible to count rows based on order of nothing:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [Column A],
   Primary_key,
   [Column C]
from Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fdec2/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an auto-increment id. Add this in your table creation code.

```
YOUR_COLUMN_A int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Then every time you insert a row, it automatically insert a row incrementing the number.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use another way, since I am not allowed to configure the tables in the database.

Comment: @marchemike but,you are saying that you want to create a column, for do that you need to change or update  you table schema.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I must have said it wrong, I'll rephrase my question. Thank you for correcting me.